# variables not or not all replaced

Tags: parsing, typo3, typoscript, substitution, fluid

In the following template I'm using three variables: `GA_TRACKING_ID`, `CC_POPUP_BGCOL` and `CC_POPUP_TXTCOL`

```html
<script src="fileadmin/templates/js/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script>
<script>
  function loadGAonConsent(){
    var gs = document.createElement("script");
    gs.async = true;
    gs.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id={GA_TRACKING_ID}";
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    h.appendChild(gs, h);
    gs.onload = function (){
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', '{GA_TRACKING_ID}', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
      testfunc('{CC_POPUP_BGCOL}', '{CC_POPUP_TXTCOL}');
    }
  }

  if(document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(item){return item.indexOf('cookieconsent_status=allow') >= 0}).length)
    loadGAonConsent();

  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    "palette": {
      "popup": {
      "background": "{CC_POPUP_BGCOL}",
      "text": "{CC_POPUP_TXTCOL}"
      },
      "button": {
      "background": "#4b81e8"
      }
    },
    "theme": "classic",
    "type": "opt-in",
    "content": {
      "policy": "policy",
      "message": "message",
      "deny": "deny",
      "allow": "allow",
      "link": "link",
      "href": "#"
    },
    onStatusChange:function(status,chosenBefore){
      if(this.hasConsented())
        loadGAonConsent();
    }
  });
</script>
```

All appearances of `GA_TRACKING_ID` are substituted as expected, but not both `CC_POPUP_xxx` in the JS-function `window.cookieconsent.initialise()`.

So I added a call to the non-existent func `testfunc('{CC_POPUP_BGCOL}', '{CC_POPUP_TXTCOL}')` right after the `gtag()` calls (to simulate a similar function call) and surprisingly these two appearances got replaced.

Can somebody explain that?

Answer (score 1):

Fluid can't know if your curly brackets belong to fluid or JavaScript. So it stops if it can't resolve one.

Try to add `{whatEver->f:format.raw()}`, in your case `'{CC_POPUP_BGCOL->f:format.raw()}'` and so on.

Comment: It's not working: `code`background": "{CC_POPUP_BGCOL->f:format.raw()}",`/code`

Comment: Did you use it on all variables?

Comment: Yes but now it's working with `<f:format.raw>{CC_POPUP_BGCOL}</f:format.raw>`

Comment: Hmm, not so nice to read in the code but good to know. Anyway @jonas is right, none-fluid curly brackets are terrible and should be avoided. I made me a custom viewHelper to render fluid variables to an js object.

Answer (score 1):

If that is a Fluid template, I strongly recommend you should not count on Fluid replacing your variables. In a template that includes JavaScript (especially with `{`) the Fluid parser is very(!!!) unreliable. Even if you have it working, that does not mean it will work after a Fluid/TYPO3 update or even on a different server.

Avoid it where possible.

I suggest to remove any variable markers from your JavaScript and instead put them into HTML and load them via JavaScript from there.

As an example:

```
<script id="cookieconsent-script" 
        src="fileadmin/templates/js/cookieconsent.min.js" 
        data-ga-tracking-id="12345ABC"` />

<script>
  var cookieconsentScriptEl = document.getElementById('cookieconsent-script')
  var gaTrackingId = cookieconsentScriptEl.dataset.gaTrackingId
</script>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: I agree with Jonas Eberle that most of the JS should be on a .js file and included in the template (either with typoscript or with a script tag in the fluid template). JS variables should also be defined in the typoscript template (using dedicated properties of PAGE).
You can also read this part of the documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/master/en-us/Fluid/ThingsToKnow/JsAndInline.html where the specific issue of JS in fluid is addressed, with all the possibles workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick Fluid into parsing mode by placing a Fluid tag inside the script tag. When doing so, I always try to separate variable definitions from actual Javascript code as much as possible.

Try something link this.

```
<script>
      <f:comment>Wake up, fluid!</f:comment>
      var ccbackground= "{CC_POPUP_BGCOL}";
      var cctext = "{CC_POPUP_TXTCOL}";
      var cctrackingId = "{GA_TRACKING_ID}";
</script>

<script src="fileadmin/templates/js/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script>
<script>
  function loadGAonConsent(){
    var gs = document.createElement("script");
    gs.async = true;
    gs.src = "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=cctrackingId";
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    h.appendChild(gs, h);
    gs.onload = function (){
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'cctrackingId', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
      testfunc('ccbackground', 'cctext');
    }
  }

  if(document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(item){return item.indexOf('cookieconsent_status=allow') >= 0}).length)
    loadGAonConsent();

  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    "palette": {
      "popup": {
      "background": ccbackground,
      "text": cctext
      },
      "button": {
      "background": "#4b81e8"
      }
    },
    "theme": "classic",
    "type": "opt-in",
    "content": {
      "policy": "policy",
      "message": "message",
      "deny": "deny",
      "allow": "allow",
      "link": "link",
      "href": "#"
    },
    onStatusChange:function(status,chosenBefore){
      if(this.hasConsented())
        loadGAonConsent();
    }
  });
</script>
```